# Problems using ganache-cli command

Tags: chainlink, ganache, brownie

It's saying that it doesn't recognize ganache-cli as a command, despite installing it and everything else as directed.

Using:

- brownie v1.17.2
- node v17.2.0 (npm v8.1.4)
- nvm 0.39.0
- Python 3.9.7
- Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2)

As part of the Solidity course [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ), specifically lesson 5. Github repo [here](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/brownie_simple_storage).

```
x@y brownie_simple_storage % brownie run scripts/deploy.py
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 50, in connect
    rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 93, in launch
    raise RPCProcessError(cmd, uri)
RPCProcessError: Unable to launch local RPC client.
Command: ganache-cli
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this can be resolved using nvm v 16.

```
nvm install 16
nvm use 16
node --version
v16.13.1

x@y brownie_simple_storage % brownie run scripts/deploy.py
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...

Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
Hello!
Terminating local RPC client...
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue you're dealing with is because ganache is already running in another active project, in order to have brownie recognize ganache is to make sure that's the only environment running ganache close to the project running the node. Which, is most likely the web3 simple storage file... not the newly created brownie file.